# Rails console: update column values with trimmed values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have some records with incorrect data in column values

```
:content => "1899-12-31T05:24:00+00:00"
:content => "1899-12-31T03:25:00+00:00"
:content => "1899-12-31T01:12:00+00:00"
```

i need to trim the front part and rear part and update data to look like this

```
:content => "05:24"
:content => "03:25"
:content => "01:12"
```

this can be achieved with trimming the front part **1899-12-31T** and rear part **:00+00:00**

please note the "content" is **string** type column,

i tried the following query but it does nothing

```
Option.where("content like '1899-12-31T%'").update_all("content = SUBSTRING(content, 1,LENGTH(content) - 6)")
```

Any help/suggestion will appreciated.

Comment: I guess your substring search doesnt work, try. `substring(content, length('1899-12-31T')+1, 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the datatype is string? because it looks kind of datetime if it is string and it is of same length in all records then you can use some method like

```
Option.each do |option|
 option.update(content: option.content[11..15])
end
```

Comment: yes datatype is string, and please describe what this line does `option.content[11..15]`

Comment: Option.each will fetch all Option records one by one and inside the loop I'm referring Option record as option (check for the case) ..once it comes inside the loop am Updating the record's content value as content[11..15]

content[11..15] = will fetch content's string from 11th index to 15th index(which is the time)